# Construction of a star (triangle inequality)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I was trying out some problems from a Russian mathematics book when this question came up. Though it seems pretty obvious that this question is to be solved through triangle inequality, yet I am unable to find sufficient conditions to get the conditions right.

[image]

As per the problem we need to prove that it is impossible to construct a star (like the one given in the picture) which satisfies: $$BC>AB,\ DE>CD,\ FG>EF,\ HI>GH,\ KA>IK.$$

P.S.: I tried to work out with some triangles like $\triangle BIF, \triangle BEH$ but unfortunately the equations seemed inconclusive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for any $△UVW$, if $VW > UW$, then $∠U > ∠V$.

Now suppose such star exists, then$$
∠BAC > ∠BCA = ∠DCE > ∠DEC = ∠FEG > ∠FGE\\
= ∠HGI > ∠HIG = ∠KIA > ∠KAI = ∠BAC,
$$
a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for such a cogent answer. Is there any solution possible using the triangle inequality?

Comment: @Harsh I dont see how triangle inequality applies here?!

Comment: @HarshSharma Even if triangle inequality were to work, it would seem to involve too many line segments to derive a contradiction. Is it required by the question to apply triangle inequality?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco I truly understand that thing. Besides that, thanks a lot for the answer.